# Is the object of abstract class is created while using anonymous inner class?

Tags: java

Having a little trouble understanding Anonymous Inner classes

Here s the code that I have.I know that WindowAdapter class is an Abstract class, then what does the line "new WindowAdapter()" means? Are we creating an object of WindowAdapter class which is an abstract class.Confused!!!

```
Class Myframe extends Frame
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Myframe f=new Myframe();
        f.setVisible(true);
        f.setSize(300,300);
        f.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter()
        {
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e)
            {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is creating an object of an anonymous class which extends `WindowAdapter` class without writing the code to subclass it.

From the [Java Tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html):

*Anonymous classes enable you to make your code more concise. They enable you to declare and instantiate a class at the same time. They are like local classes except that they do not have a name.*

This is a shortcut to create an object of a subclass without explicitly writing a separate class which extends `WindowAdapter`.The point is that you need the object from inside the code of a method so you never refer to them elsewhere, so you don't need to create a separate class for them.

Comment: So, are you saying that there is some class without name which is extending WindowAdapter and by using "new WindowAdapter()" , we are actually creating the object of that anonymous class,rite?

Comment: Also perhaps worth noting is that the `XxxAdapter` classes give you a handy way to implement 'part' of an interface (in this case, `WindowListener`) without having to implement all of the methods - the other ones (`windowOpened`, `windowIconified`, etc) just do nothing.

Answer (score 1):

Its no more abstract as you have implemented the abstract method with System.exit(0)

Answer (score 0):

It creates an implementation of `WindowAdapter` at Runtime and the implementation consists of the code you have provided. It's called `anonymous`, because it doesn't have a name, therefore you cannot refer it by name. When it's executed once, it cannot be executed again.

Answer (score 0):

You are subclassing the `WindowAdapter` class and you provide an implementation and instantiate it at the same time. This is what basically happens here.

This is called an anonymous inner class.

As others suggested here the [java tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html) are containing excellent explanations about this.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't create the Object of Abstract Class directly, But you can use an anonymous inner class to do that and you also can implement your own methods inside the anonymous class. 
Please refer - http://www.easybix.com/can-create-object-abstract-class/